# Create a hash with multiple values from 2 arrays in powershell

Tags: powershell, data-partitioning

I want to create a hash with multiple values for each key, from 2 arrays A & B which are unequal in size.

```
$A = @('usr1','usr2', 'usr3', 'usr4')
$B = @('INC1','INC2','INC3','INC4','INC5','INC6')
$h = [ordered]@{}
for($i=0; $i -lt $B.Count; $i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j -lt $A.Count; $j++)
    {
        $h[$A[$j]] += @($B[$j])
    }
}
```

`
Output I am getting

```
Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
usr1                           {INC1, INC2, INC3, INC4...}                     
usr2                           {INC1, INC2, INC3, INC4...}                     
usr3                           {INC1, INC2, INC3, INC4...}                     
usr4                           {INC1, INC2, INC3, INC4...}
```

Desired Output:

```
Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
usr1                           {INC1, INC5}                     
usr2                           {INC2, INC6}                     
usr3                           {INC3}           
usr4                           {INC4}
```

I need to distribute the items from array B to Array A members in equal manner.
That is, the elements of `$B` should be collected in hashtable entries named for the elements of `$A` one after the other, until no more `$B` items are left.

What am I doing wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the modulo operator (`%`) to "wrap around" at the end any value that exceeds the length of the smallest array:

```
$table = [ordered] @{}
for($i = 0; $i -lt $B.Count; $i++){
  $table[$A[$i % $A.Count]] += @($B[$i])
}
```

Comment: Sure thing; nice answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mathias. It worked like a charm.